# Return products if Category is not Active

Tags: magento

How can I make `$cat->getProductCollection();` to return products if the category is NOT ACTIVE

It's been a very long time. I could not make this to work.

This is what I am doing. But no Luck

```
        private function _getCollection() {

    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active',array('eq'=>False))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('eq'=>'61'))
    ->load();

        foreach($category as $cat){            

        $Prods = $cat->getProductCollection();                     
        $Prods->addWebsiteFilter();            
        $Prods->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        }


           return $Prods;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);

foreach ($cat as $category){
$cat_id = $category->getId();
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($cat_id);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($collection as $_product) {
echo $_product->getName();
}
```

}